# Track Google App Engine X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars server side

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I know that if you're logged in as admin on developer console, Google App Engine adds in **X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars** to the response headers. I was wondering if there's an API that I can use server side to track the usage.

Or is there any other way to measure usage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Cloud Platform Billing API](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2013/12/ow-get-programmatic-access-to-your-billing-data-with-new-billing-api.html) to monitor your daily usage.

Comment: Thanks for that info. But I'm trying to figure out a way to charge each user using the app based on the requests they make. Is there an way to achieve that using the billing api?

Comment: No, but it does not seem cost efficient, because you'll need to write to the datastore for every request made by the user, to save the billing info. This will make your costs explode. You'd better use an approximation. For example if you're building a marketplace and charging the vendors,then the number of items in the vendor's catalogue  is a good approximation. An even better one is the total amount purchased by users.

Comment: David has the core of it.  It IS feasible, because you can log everything the user does.... but it'll at least double your costs since everything will be in datastore.  One way would be to use the Logs API (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/functions) to analyze your logs.... again not super easy, and definitely rough if you have a lot of usage and run out of log space.